# How to monitor how much memory my App is consuming?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa

From time to time, different Apps I am developing close itself, I'm assuming it is because of memory usage that the IOS kills once it is to high.

Even if it is not because of memory I will like to find out how much memory my app is consuming every step of the way.

**Update**:
Thanks guys, I understand Instruments purpose, but my Idea was to monitor memory while I am using the app not connected to the computer. For instance, something like placing a UILabel Text content with the current memory consumption.

Any directions?

Comment: Instruments http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's using instrument to profile  your application. Using Allocation mode, you can find out :
- how much memory your app using. 
- how many objects of your app are allocated in memory.
- Which objects (GUI, NSOBjects, bla bla bla) are allocated in memory.
- Your app using more or less memory after you do somethings in your app.

More detail:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

Apple [Instruments User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good way to start. There is a chapter devoted to [locating memory issues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW1). To monitor memory consumption, Allocations, Leaks and Activity Monitor instruments will be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'instruments'. Run -> Profile